# CORS error on React with Django deployed on heroku

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I've been trying to use React + Django rest framework

I've deployed the API on heroku and configured the settings.py with django-cors-headers,

My settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders', 
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'account',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

but when I make a post request with React on localhost I get:

```
login:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'myapi' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

My React:

```
const login = async (email, password) => {

    const response = await createSession(email, password);
    

    console.log('login', response.data);

    const loggedUser = response;
    const token = response.data.access;

    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(loggedUser));
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);

    api.defaults.headers.Authorization = Bearer ${token};

    setUser(loggedUser);
    navigate('/');
};
```

Comment: Use Allowed_hosts = [*] , to allow calls from react .